# Spinor and Scalar Bose-Einstein condensate

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-field-theory, condensed-matter, bose-einstein-condensate

I read about an order paramater that describes a Bose-Einstein condensate. But I don't understand, the classification into "scalar" condensate and "spinor" one. Is it linked with spin of atoms that take part in condensation? Or is it a property of the condensate?

Does anyone have a good explanation?

Comment: See e.g. http://arxiv.org/abs/1001.2072 for spinor BE condensates.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You call the condensate 'scalar' when the atoms are spin-0. When instead atoms have a non trivial spin you talk about 'spinor condensates'.